# How can i find the sum of an attribute in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

How can i get write a controller method to get the summation of all the marks attributes in the AsComponent Class. I want to get the total marks in the Ascomponents. I want build a controller method so that i can connect it with my react frontend.

```
public class AsComponent
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AsID { get; set; }
        public string Ascomponent { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LOID")]
        public int? Lid { get; set; } 
        public string LOID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("POId")]
        public string? POID { get; set; }
        public int Marks { get; set; }
        public string LD { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my controller. It is auto generated and i have done to some edits.

```
namespace GroupProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AsComponentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ObeDbContext _context;

        public AsComponentsController(ObeDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/AsComponents
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AsComponent>>> GetAsComponents()
        {
            return await _context.AsComponents.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/AsComponents/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AsComponent>> GetAsComponent(int id)
        {
            var asComponent = await _context.AsComponents.FindAsync(id);

            if (asComponent == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return asComponent;
        }

        // POST: api/AsComponents
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AsComponent>> PostAsComponent(AsComponent asComponent)
        {
            _context.AsComponents.Add(asComponent);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetAsComponent", new { id = asComponent.AsID }, asComponent);
        }

        // DELETE: api/AsComponents/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AsComponent>> DeleteAsComponent(int id)
        {
            var asComponent = await _context.AsComponents.FindAsync(id);
            if (asComponent == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.AsComponents.Remove(asComponent);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return asComponent;
        }

        private bool AsComponentExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.AsComponents.Any(e => e.AsID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the Marks properties together it should be enough to call:

```
var marksSum = _context.AsCompoments.Sum(component => component.Marks)
```